# Errors and glitches using Youtube Api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I am using youtube's APi for my website where videos I upload and save to a specific website are posted. The thing is that where I upload the page where my posted videos are shown, The first one shows a "video" with my channel name and it's not really a video but it has an id and all that. But it is invisible on my youtube channel and I have not uploaded that type of video on my channel. Down at the bottom are the php code Api code:

I've also gotten the thumbnail's of every video to show on the website but some videos does not show the thumbnail.

Now to the last thing I get these error's in the console while having the APi's

- `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
- `Error parsing header 
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appser

ve/security-bugs/log/youtube: 
insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. 
The default protections will be applied.`

```
<?php

function get_videos()
{
  $json_link="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=Api-key&channelId=Channel_id&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10";

  $json = file_get_contents($json_link);
  $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

  if( isset($obj['items']) )
  {
    foreach($obj['items'] as $post)
    {
      $id = isset($post['id']['videoId']) ? $post['id']['videoId'] : "";
      $published_at = isset($post['snippet']['publishedAt']) ? $post['snippet']['publishedAt'] : "";
      $title = isset($post['snippet']['title']) ? $post['snippet']['title'] : "";
      $description = isset($post['snippet']['description']) ? $post['snippet']['description'] : "";
      $thumbnail = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$id}/maxresdefault.jpg";


        ?>
        <div class="row grid-list-wrapper no-gutter-space" id="shots">
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item container2">
      <div>
        <div class="middle2">
            <p class="text2"><strong><?php echo $title;?></strong></p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <img data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="<?php echo "#modal_$id";?>"
            src="<?php echo "$thumbnail";?>"
            class="image2" style="height:220px;width:390px;" />
          </div>

    <center>
        <div class="modal" id="<?php echo "modal_$id";?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

          <h2 style="color:white;"><?php echo $title;?>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <?php
              echo
                "<iframe width=\"720\" height=\"410\""
                ." src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$id\" frameborder=\"0\""
                ." allowfullscreen></iframe>";
                ?>
          </div>

  </div>
    </center>
       <?php
    }
  } else {echo "Videos could not be found or something went wrong :(";}
}
?>
```

This is the JSON file for the api script is:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/xToA0H6y7a6RTmJrkSY6DXE6gs8\"",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 5,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/ndFVPddFgdf4xczeyIcPBlONiRo\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "pKFoAuyIHuE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-02-24T22:14:30.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCdLRwYrtYj1ZsNKu0lxk9aA",
    "title": "Hihi",
    "description": "Website: https://swedcraft.net/",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pKFoAuyIHuE/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pKFoAuyIHuE/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pKFoAuyIHuE/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Linus Janns",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/J_uNqMQXteA_1q6gSm2oN54DADE\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "_ja8k6MHjE0"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-02-12T15:47:37.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCdLRwYrtYj1ZsNKu0lxk9aA",
    "title": "Some vines",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_ja8k6MHjE0/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_ja8k6MHjE0/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_ja8k6MHjE0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Linus Janns",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/yPTJujmfy2l1U5kTi9lZlHaCFRo\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "7AxKOlZ-Qe8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-02-11T05:21:04.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCdLRwYrtYj1ZsNKu0lxk9aA",
    "title": "Toilet prank gone wrong",
    "description": "website: https://www.swedcraft.net *–OBSERVE: These videos I post on this channel is for my website, if you (the owner) don't want them on the web or youtube please contact me insted of striking...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7AxKOlZ-Qe8/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7AxKOlZ-Qe8/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7AxKOlZ-Qe8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Linus Janns",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/Es-CoB_YMSvsz47s_9TcID7n2_c\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "SwiEwLhIQIY"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-02-11T05:09:43.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCdLRwYrtYj1ZsNKu0lxk9aA",
    "title": "Doggie love",
    "description": "website: https://www.swedcraft.net *–OBSERVE: These videos I post on this channel is for my website, if you (the owner) don't want them on the web or youtube please contact me insted of striking...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SwiEwLhIQIY/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SwiEwLhIQIY/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SwiEwLhIQIY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Linus Janns",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/tZpA7tgs5ehyQDs7U6hSefhbKuM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCdLRwYrtYj1ZsNKu0lxk9aA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-02-10T05:57:10.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCdLRwYrtYj1ZsNKu0lxk9aA",
    "title": "Linus Janns",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-XHBR63N3tYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/7oSIIyAvQO0/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-XHBR63N3tYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/7oSIIyAvQO0/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-XHBR63N3tYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/7oSIIyAvQO0/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Linus Janns",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was that I added:

```
$url= isset($post['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']) ? $post['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'] : "";
```

to the code which would get the url of the video and then I added

```
     if( 0 == strcmp($url, "THE_URL_OF_THE_VIDEO") )
    {
    continue;
    }
```

This would remove the whole video from the website. It is still unclear why it appeared in the first place as I could not find any information on it at all but I've now fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in current Google Chrome and Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807304

In the current version of their browser Chrome developers had restricted the X-XSS-Protection's report field URL to the same domain origin for some security reasons. So, when you embed video with some embed code, at it downloads from another server where the header report=https://www.google.com/ is set, and while your page is not hosted at google.com domain - the error message occurs.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea why I see a video that doesn't exist ? En example is the one called Linus Janns. That is the name of my channel (https://swedcraft.net/v)

Comment: Can you reframe the question

Comment: It shows a video that I have definitely not uploaded to my youtube channel. The video has my channel name with no thumbnail and I cannot the video on my youtube channel. Some how the php script picks up a video that do not exist.

Comment: You should probably check with the normal YouTube API check and then then check whether you are getting any video details in your json.

Comment: I made an edit to the post with the JSON file. I checked with the original youtube api and I still have the same problem. It picks up an non existing video. :/ You can see the "video" at the bottom